# Render radio buttons

Tags: visualforce

I have two radio buttons Yes or No in VF page. based on User profile I have to shoe the buttons. For suppose if the profile is a Director level display both "Yes" and "No".Lowe than Director profile, display only "Yes"..

```
<apex:slecectRadio value="{!ProceedWithPlan}" Id= '''proceedWithPlanId" rendered =""{!isProfileAboveDirector}'>
<apex:selectoption itemLabel ="Yes" itemvalue="yes" id="yesid">
</apex:selectoption>
<apex:selectoption itemLabel ="No" itemvalue="No" id="noId">
</apex:selectoption>.
</apex:slecectRadio>

<apex:slecectRadio value="{!ProceedWithPlan}" Id= '''proceedWithPlanId" rendered =""{!NOT(isProfileAboveDirector)}'>
<apex:selectoption itemLabel ="Yes" itemvalue="yes" id="yesid">
</apex:selectoption>
</apex:slecectRadio>
```

Error :Duplicate Id..Plz help me with this..

Comment: <apex:slecectRadio value="{!ProceedWithPlan}" Id= '''proceedWithPlanId" rendered =""{!isProfileAboveDirector}'>
<apex:selectoption itemLabel ="Yes" itemvalue="yes" id="yesid">
</apex:selectoption>
<apex:selectoption itemLabel ="No" itemvalue="No" id="noId">
</apex:selectoption>.
</apex:slecectRadio>

<apex:slecectRadio value="{!ProceedWithPlan}" Id= '''proceedWithPlanId" rendered =""{!NOT(isProfileAboveDirector)}'>
<apex:selectoption itemLabel ="Yes" itemvalue="yes" id="yesid">
</apex:selectoption>
</apex:slecectRadio>

Error :Duplicate Id..Plz help me with this..

Answer (score 1):

You can write this like this. Your VF page:

```
<apex:form>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!ProceedWithPlan}" Id= "proceedWithPlanId" >
    <apex:selectoption itemLabel ="Yes" itemvalue="yes" id="yesid" rendered ="{!isProfileAboveDirector}"> </apex:selectoption>
    <apex:selectoption itemLabel ="No" itemvalue="No" id="noId"> </apex:selectoption>
</apex:selectRadio>
</apex:form>
```

And your controller for that page:

```
public Boolean ProceedWithPlan {get; set;}
public Boolean isProfileAboveDirector {get; set;}
```

Please rate my answer if this helps you.

Comment: `rendered ="{!isProfileAboveDirector}"` should be on the `No` option.

Comment: He want that two buttons render if isProfileAboveDirector == true. So my answer is right.